# My re-hydrated yeast has lost a lot of his foam, is it alive?

Tags: yeast

Today was a brew day for me, and while I was waiting for the water to boil, I re-hydrated my yeast. 
Unfortunately my wort didn't cool as fast as I Hoped and my yeast starter lost all of it's foam in the meantime. 
Is it dead? Can I still use the yeast some how?

Comment: How much time was there between making your yeast starter and the moment you could pitch? Did you even make a starter, or did you just re-hydrate dry yeast?

Comment: About 4 and a half hours. There's a difference between making a yeast starter and re-hydrate dry yeast? I think I just re-hydrated

Comment: A starter is putting yeast in a small volume or wort so it starts its metabolism and potentially starts growing. Putting dry yeast in water is just rehydrating it but no appreciable metabolism starts.  If you just put it in water it does tend to foam some but that foam means nothing.  Certainly nothing when it falls/fades.

Comment: Side note, how do you know it is a he?

Comment: Noted, will not assume gender in the future (it's 2017 after all)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't have a problem. Yeast does not die that fast. You can still use the rehydrated yeast, it will get active back again when you pitch it in your wort. If you did not cover it, then just hope that nothing else gets in your wort also.